# I'm stuck on a custom linked list

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm supposed to be making a linked list without using structures, just arrays. Everything works like the instructor wants it to, except Tom is supposed to be the end of the list, and needs to have the if statement displayed. That's the only thing I can't get to work. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int position[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    string names[10] = {"dick", "Harry", "Sam", "Tom"};
    int link[10] = {1, 2, 3, 99, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, };
    int stkptr = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(stkptr == 99)
            cout<<"You have reached the end of the list."<<endl;
        else
            stkptr = link[stkptr];
        cout << names[i] << " is in position " 
             <<position[stkptr] << " and is linked to " << names[stkptr] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your formatting suggests that you want `cout << ...` to be in the else branch too. If so you would have to enclose the whole branch in `{}` like `else { sktptr ... names[stkptr] << endl;}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. what help? What is your question about a programming language?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The first 3 names display everything like they're supposed to. Once Tom is displayed I need the cout in the if statement to be displayed. So far I can't get that to show

Comment: @Dorden: That is not a question about a programming language. It is a statement of fact about your progress so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links are not set up correctly.

The 99 in `link[3]` indicates there is no 4th node in the list, only 3.

You want to move the 99 to after your last valid link.

Hint: your list goes: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 99, showing only valid nodes 0, 1, 2.

Hint 2: Draw it using pen and paper.

*If you like this answer, click the check mark next to it.*

Answer (score 1):

Nobody's comment about your else statement needing brackets I think addresses the fact that the else will only execute the first line that follows. So,

```
else
    stkptr = link[stkptr];
    cout<<names[i]<<" is in position "<<position[stkptr]<<" and is linked to "<<names[stkptr]<<endl;
```

will only execute the `stkptr = link[stkptr];` if the conditional failed, but the cout will always be executed.

The broader issue though has to do with an out-of-bound array index. You don't get to see Tom because your are getting a stack overflow. The issue here is that you are setting `stkptr` to be `link[stkptr]` before your cout. When `i == 3` you will have:

```
cout<<names[3]<<" is in position "<<position[99]<<" and is linked to "<<names[99]<<endl;
```

You have to restructure the program so you are setting `stkptr` to 99 after any array lookups, and you have to add some more logic to not cout the whole `" and is linked to "...` when you are looking at Tom because he isn't linked to anyone.